# Error in extracting the values in a column of a Spark Dataframe to a list using RDD.Flatmap

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to create a histogram using the statistical data in a spark data frame. When I try to extract a column values into a list it gives me below error. I am executing this command in Jupiter Notebook and OS is windows. After going through several answers in the community I also tried downgrading Java to Java8, updated PATH variables correctly. But I have a doubt whether I have correctly configured the clusters. Can someone help me to resolve my issue please. Error I am getting is below.

Thank You!

**Error:**

> Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
> Cell In[49], line 1
> 1 blood_pressure_values = df_cleaned.select('BloodPressure').rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
>
> File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py:1814, in RDD.collect(self)
> 1812 with SCCallSiteSync(self.context):
> 1813     assert self.ctx._jvm is not None
> 1814     sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
> 1815 return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, self._jrdd_deserializer))
>
> File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1322, in JavaMember.**call**(self, *args)
> 1316 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +
> 1317     self.command_header +
> 1318     args_command +
> 1319     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
> 1321 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
> 1322 return_value = get_return_value(
> 1323     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
> 1325 for temp_arg in temp_args:
> 1326     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):
>
> File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py:169, in capture_sql_exception..deco(*a, **kw)
> 167 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
> 168     try:
> 169         return f(*a, **kw)
> 170     except Py4JJavaError as e:
> 171         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)
>
> File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
> 324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
> 325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
> 327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
> 328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
> 329 else:
> 330     raise Py4JError(
> 331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
> 332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))
>
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 65.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 65.0 (TID 59) (Sushi executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:192)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:109)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:166)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:92)
> at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:139)
> at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:554)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1529)
> at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:557)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
> at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
> at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
> at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
> at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
> at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
> at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:179)
> 15 more
>
> Driver stacktrace:
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2785)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2721)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2720)
> at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
> at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
> at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2720)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)
> at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2984)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2923)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2912)
> at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:971)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2263)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2284)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2303)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2328)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1019)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:405)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1018)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:193)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
> at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
> at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
> at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
> at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
> at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:192)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:109)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:166)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:92)
> at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:139)
> at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:554)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1529)
> at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:557)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
> 1 more
> Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
> at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
> at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
> at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
> at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
> at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
> at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:179)
> 15 more

Comment: how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: too much code, please reduce to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example